# Create a list of values/keys from a dictionary with a final data type of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a better way? I'm fairly new at coding in general and I'm taking up python as my first language. I'm working with a list containing several dictionaries.

```
cities = [{'City': 'Buenos Aires',  'Country': 'Argentina',  'Population': 2891,  'Area': 203}, {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 2732, 'Area': 630}, {'City': 'Pyeongchang', 'Country': 'South Korea', 'Population': 44, 'Area': 1464},
```

I needed say I need to access the dictionary containing PyeongChang and return a list of the values in that list that also are of the list data type and not the dict data type, this is how i managed it. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution? Thanks in advance!

```
pyeongchang = cities[3] 
pyeongchang_values = list() for i in pyeongchang.values():
pyeongchang_values.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code isn't complete and causes errors if run. Also, the length of the list `cities` is 3, so `cities[3]` causes an index error and should be `cities[2]`. Secondly be mindful of how your code is formatted in the questions (your for loop does not start on a new line)

Now to answer your question, you can produce the same result with one line of code:
`pyeongchang_values = list(cities[2].values())`

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to quote code properly in the question but it looks like you've answered my question effectively. thank you!

Comment: my i ask if there is an easily referenced resource that contains common syntax in lines like this? as a newbie it is hard to tell when a ()/{}/[] is called for... for example is the open close parenthesis here `pyeongchang_values = list(cities[2].values()#<---#)` only required when its inside of a list or something of the like? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure about there being an easy resource as such, but I think it would help to learn and understand different python datatypes and how functions work (with brackets vs dot notation) through lessons that are widely available on YouTube and more. Beyond that, the more experience you have coding the better you'll understand.

Comment: The open-close parentheses here just has to do with how .values() works. Learning about classes, attributes, and methods would help you understand that. Also, `#` comments do not work in the way that you have done to show the arrow (ie. you cannot end a comment by adding another `#` as you have done).